# Newly created spark executor running in kubernetes doesn't know ignite configuration

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I have a spark driver & executor running on kubernetes and executor talks to apache ignite instance. But if `executor-1` dies, `executor-2` will get created by the driver.

Now newly created `executor-2` is complaining about executor 2):

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteIllegalStateException: Ignite instance with provided name doesn't exist. Did you call Ignition.start(..) to start an Ignite instance? [name=shared-grid]

at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.grid(IgnitionEx.java:1390)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.ignite(Ignition.java:531)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.package$.ignite(package.scala:86)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider$$anonfun$configProvider$1$2.apply(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:226)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider$$anonfun$configProvider$1$2.apply(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:223)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.Once.apply(IgniteContext.scala:224)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.ignite(IgniteContext.scala:145)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteSQLDataFrameRDD.compute(IgniteSQLDataFrameRDD.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there anything we need to do to pass ignite instance details to newly create executor instance

Comment: What's `shared-grid`? In which JVM is it supposed to run?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the **IgniteSparkSession**? I can't find the ticket but it looks like a known issue that sometimes IgniteSparkSession can't start the internal clients on a physically distributed cluster. Next code:

```
IgniteSparkSession igniteSession = IgniteSparkSession.builder()
               .appName("Spark Ignite catalog example")
               .igniteConfig(configPath)
               .getOrCreate();
```

Can produce the following exception:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteIllegalStateException: Ignite instance with provided name doesn't exist. Did you call Ignition.start(..) to start an Ignite instance? [name=grid]
```

As the workaround, you can try to start the client node with the provided configuration of every spark node before starting the job but I am not sure that it will work normally.

I suggest to avoid using **IgniteSparkSession** until the current issue will not be fixed.

Please use the DataFrame API syntax:

```
String configPath = "client.xml";

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
 .setAppName("Example");

SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
 .config(sparkConf)
 .getOrCreate();

Dataset < Row > csvDataset = session.read()
 .format("csv")
 .option("sep", ",")
 .option("header", true)
 .load("person.csv");

Dataset < Row > resultDF = csvDataset
 .select("id", "name", "city_id", "company")
 .sort("id")
 .limit(10000);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 DataFrameWriter < Row > df = resultDF
  .write()
  .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE())
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), configPath)
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(), "Person")
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS(), "id, city_id")
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS(), "template=partitioned,backups=1")
  .mode(Append);

 df.save();
}

session.close();
```

This code works fine. I will check the JIRA issue for it. Probably I will create a new one.

UPDATE: here is the new ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12637

Comment: Yes. We use IgniteSparkSession

Comment: Any idea if this issue is fixed in latest ignite version

Comment: No, but you can try to start a thread on Ignite developer least. Probably somebody will be able to help there.